# IDA Pro: function to return first valid address

Tags: ida, idapython

The IDA Pro Python function ScreenEA() will return the address the cursor is at and if I manually position the cursor at the start, it will return the first valid address.

However, I would like to be able to position my cursor anywhere and be able to ask for what the first valid address is. What function will return that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use `MinEA()`, which is [equivalent to](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/650.shtml) `GetLongPrm(INF_MIN_EA)`.

From [IDA's documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/285.shtml):

```
INF_MIN_EA      // int32; The lowest address used
                //        in the program
```